# Refreshing DIV on HTML page or only PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

As mentioned in my other question where I found help and learned a lot: I am a beginner so please be patient with me...

Ok, I have a page containing some JS which gets the hour, checks what time it is, and changes an area on the page. Since these are radio shows which change about every two hours, I would need to update this. I don't want to reload the entire page, just refresh the content for the ID's.

I thought this would work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#refreshButton').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'Wednesday.html',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(response) {
        $('#imgContainer').html(response);
        $('#status').html(response);
        $('#showon').html(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Handle the error 
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This doesn't work. It loads, but the output is not as expected. I know there are a lot of posts with this question, but I researched for two days now and can't find the solution.

Can you give me a hint? It's an HTML page not PHP. Is that even possible?

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: whats output in the response? (yes it's fetching an html file but whats in that file, how is the response formatted , what is the unexpected output)

Comment: Here the code from wednesday.html, not the whole but I think its enough to see what I do there. The unexpected outcome is, sometimes it shows the divs and sometimes it doesnt.

`<b><span class="blinking"><span  id="status"></span></span></b></font>      <div id="imageContainer"></div>
 <b> <span id="showon"></span></b>`

Comment: @AndYman What do you get if you console.log the output? Are you familiar with browser developer tools? If you open your dev tools to the console, you can see the output of a console.log(response).

Comment: @freedomn-m Why won't it run any JS? Assigning to `.innerHTML` doesn't run scripts, but jQuery `.html()` does.

Comment: If you're not seeing everything, it could be due to CSS that hides it.

Comment: If you examine the `#imgContainer` element in the Elements inspector, do you see the returned HTML?